# How to request data to JSON-RPC using python

Tags: python, json, json-rpc

I want to dump some data from a website with JSON-RPC but i cant get any information. I'm using post request and even simulating headers using python but seems like isn't enough...

Im getting this error: {"error":{"code":590,"msg":"couldn't parse request arguments"}}

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib,urllib2,json,httplib

url = 'localhost'
parameters = {'method':'buscador.obtenerGruposAsignaturas',"params":json.dumps(["2025333","0"])}
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
'Content-Length' : len(data),
"Referer":"localhost",
"Cookie":'JSESSIONID=2C6BBA00328C1C2F67794E50337D6E3A.N1TS002'
"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1'}
conn=httplib.HTTPConnection(url,80)
conn.request("POST","/search/JSON-RPC",data,headers)



page = conn.getresponse().read()
print page
```

Thanks for comments or suggestions

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JSON-RPC, perhaps you should encode `parameters` in json and not urlencode?

Comment: You mean:    parameters = {'method':'search.searchGroup',"params":json.dumps(["2012","0"])} # Didnt work :S

Comment: A gotcha that got me, too: if using the `requests` library, beware that `requests.post`'s second argument is `data` and you don't want to put your params there, but rather in its third argument, `json`, that is for the OP's example: `requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)`.